# What does the .find() method's result(an integer value) mean?

Tags: python

How is it calculated?  I understand the range part to it, what character you want it to start at and which one you want it to end at.  But it produces an integer value, how is this integer value calculated and what does it mean?

```
quote = 'Let it be, let it be, let it be'

result = quote.find('let it')
print("Substring 'let it':", result)

result = quote.find('small')
print("Substring 'small ':", result)

# How to use find()
if  (quote.find('be,') != -1):
  print("Contains substring 'be,'")
else:
  print("Doesn't contain substring")
```

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find

(Got the code from here)^^  It has compiler on the website.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: The result is `position` of the first occurence of the substring. `L` and `l` are different so it finds it on "11th" index, "12th" character. "-1" if not found.

Comment: also you get negative responses for your question because this one is a basic part of any language you could find on documentations.

Comment: I just didn't understand how the answer was worded.  Index definitions weren't matching up. https://www.bing.com/search?q=index+definitions&qs=AS&pq=index+def&sk=AS2&sc=8-9&cvid=671D2A0E8B964E8E846478BE757D849D&FORM=QBRE&sp=3

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation ([link](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html#l2h-183))?

It returns the index of the first occurrence of the substring you're looking for, or -1 if it isn't in the string

Comment: What do you mean index?  It returns the count of characters?

Comment: Yes I did, I am not familiar with what an index is.

Comment: @Thomas an index is a location in an array.  A string is (in many languages) an array of characters.  So the string ```"Let it be"``` has `'L'` at index `0`, `'e'` at index `1`, and so on.  This idea of an index applies to python strings and lists, among other things

Answer (score 0):

```
Python indexes for a six-character string: my_str = 'abcdef'
Indexes enumerate the characters.

Index from front:    0   1   2   3   4   5  
                   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
                   | a | b | c | d | e | f |
                   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You might want to read up on "slice notation".

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes.find(sub[, start[, end]])
```

and

```
bytearray.find(sub[, start[, end]])
```

Return the lowest index in the data where the subsequence sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.
The subsequence to search for may be any bytes-like object or an integer in the range 0 to 255.